# Replaced Optane with SSD and Now my Laptop Won't Power Up

Tags: windows, battery, hp-pavilion

I have a Pavilion - 15t-Cs000 CTO. I removed the battery, replaced the Optane with the SSD in the M.2 slot, and placed the battery back in. Now, there are no lights and the laptop shows no sign of life. Before the process, the battery was at 100%. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Put things back as they were?

Comment: I've tried that, no luck...

Comment: Then something went wrong in the process. Please take it to tech service. It's not possible to diagnose and make suggestions for that remotely.